# Ultratab header resizing after image was added

Tags: image, tabs, header, resize, infragistics

Here is my question. When I try to add ImageList to tabcontrol, it's all ok except one thing: tab control's header is getting bigger. it depends on size of image I suppose. So could you please help me and tell me how can I add image without resizing tab control's header width? Or how can I get access to tab control's header programmatically so that I can set it's width by myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image size applying a value to the property

```
 UltraTabControl1.ImageSize = new Size(24,24);
```

Also, there is a property that allows to stop the image to fill the space defined by ImageSize.

```
 ultraTabControl1.ScaleImages = Infragistics.Win.ScaleImage.Never;
```

Comment: No, there is something that i don't need...you see, i want to set imagesize bigger then 24x24 (lets say 32x32). BUT! i want my header be the same size as if i add image 24x24. now it becomes bigger.

Comment: You can set the ImageSize to 24x24 to fix the height of the tabcontrol header and then set ScaleImages to ScaleImage.Always. (Of course the image is stretched to be visible in a 24 pixels height)

Comment: still no success...i try to set imagesize to 24x24 and then set ScaleImages to Always, but i get too small images when run my application. And if i'm trying to make images bigger in another part of code (while my application is starting i have 24x24) i haven't got any changes - caption is getting bigger

Comment: When you added the images to the ImageList what was the value of the ImageSize property on the ImageList? I suspect that your images are scaled to the ImageSize set on the ImageList.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the tab by setting [FixedWidth](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinTabControl.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTabControl.UltraTab~FixedWidth.html) of the tab:

```
this.ultraTabControl1.Tabs[0].FixedWidth = 100;
```